# alphanumeric sort in VIM

Tags: sorting, vim, alphanumeric

Suppose I have a list in a text file which is as follows -

```
TaskB_115
TaskB_19
TaskB_105
TaskB_13
TaskB_10
TaskB_0_A_1
TaskB_17
TaskB_114
TaskB_110
TaskB_0_A_5
TaskB_16
TaskB_12
TaskB_113
TaskB_15
TaskB_103
TaskB_2
TaskB_18
TaskB_106
TaskB_11
TaskB_14
TaskB_104
TaskB_112
TaskB_107
TaskB_0_A_4
TaskB_102
TaskB_100
TaskB_109
TaskB_101
TaskB_0_A_2
TaskB_0_A_3
TaskB_116
TaskB_1_A_0
TaskB_111
TaskB_108
```

If I sort in vim with command `%sort`, it gives me output as -

```
TaskB_0_A_1
TaskB_0_A_2
TaskB_0_A_3
TaskB_0_A_4
TaskB_0_A_5
TaskB_10
TaskB_100
TaskB_101
TaskB_102
TaskB_103
TaskB_104
TaskB_105
TaskB_106
TaskB_107
TaskB_108
TaskB_109
TaskB_11
TaskB_110
TaskB_111
TaskB_112
TaskB_113
TaskB_114
TaskB_115
TaskB_116
TaskB_12
TaskB_13
TaskB_14
TaskB_15
TaskB_16
TaskB_17
TaskB_18
TaskB_19
TaskB_1_A_0
TaskB_2
```

But I would like to have the output as follows -

```
TaskB_0_A_1
TaskB_0_A_2
TaskB_0_A_3
TaskB_0_A_4
TaskB_0_A_5
TaskB_1_A_0
TaskB_2
TaskB_10
TaskB_11
TaskB_12
TaskB_13
TaskB_14
TaskB_15
TaskB_16
TaskB_17
TaskB_18
TaskB_19
TaskB_100
TaskB_101
TaskB_102
TaskB_103
TaskB_104
TaskB_105
TaskB_106
TaskB_107
TaskB_108
TaskB_109
TaskB_110
TaskB_111
TaskB_112
TaskB_113
TaskB_114
TaskB_115
TaskB_116
```

**Note** I just wrote this list to demonstrate the problem. I could generate the list in VIM. But I want to do it for other things as well in VIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With [n] sorting is done on the first decimal number
            in the line (after or inside a {pattern} match).
            One leading '-' is included in the number.
```

try this command:

```
sor n
```

and you don't need the `%`, sort sorts all lines if no range was given.

**EDIT**

as commented by OP, if you have:

```
TaskB_0_A_1
TaskB_0_A_2
TaskB_0_A_4
TaskB_0_A_3
TaskB_0_A_5
TaskB_1_A_0
```

you could try:

```
sor n /.*_\ze\d*/
```

or

```
sor nr /\d*$/
```

**EDIT2**

for newly edited question, this line may give you expected output based on your example data:

```
sor nr /\d*$/|sor n
```

Comment: oh yes, what i was trying was like this `%!sort -n`. 
also can i edit my question. suppose I had my list as - 
`TaskB_0_A_1
TaskB_0_A_2
TaskB_0_A_4
TaskB_0_A_3
TaskB_0_A_5
TaskB_1_A_0
` and then do the sort, it doesn't work. Can you tell me, how to achieve sorting of this, since `sort n` does sorting only on first decimal number.

Comment: @Raj pls edit your question then. but next time try to make the example better fit for your real data. this helps you get solution faster also save effort of people who will give help.